# Is CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage() an async method in Chrome70

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I want to render a video in a canvas with 25fps or more. So I use `CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()` to render every frame in the canvas. It works in chrome69 and FireFox. But it does not work in chrome70.

Here is the code fragment:

```
if (frame >= this.inFrame && frame <= this.outFrame) {
    // this.ctx.drawImage(this.video,
    //    this.sourceRect.x, this.sourceRect.y, this.sourceRect.width, this.sourceRect.height,
    //    this.rect.x, this.rect.y, this.rect.width, this.rect.height);

    this.frame.init(this.canvas);   // line 6, breakpoint here.
    this.frame.isPlaying = this.isPlaying;
    let image = this.frame;

    for (let i = 0; i<this.filters.length;i++) {
        image = this.filters[i].getImageWithFilter(frame, image);
    }

    return image;
}
```

I put a breakpoint at line 6. At this time, The video is loaded.

```
this.video.readyState=4
```

And I execute this command in dev tools.

```
document.getElementById("test_canvas").getContext('2d').drawImage(this.video, 0, 0);
```

Sometimes the test canvas shows the correct video frame, sometimes not, just nothing to show.
Let's keep the program going on, the canvas will show the correct video frame finally.

So I doubt that the `CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()` is an async method in Chrome70. But I find nothing in Chrome website.

Could anyone help me with this question or help me render correctly in every frames.

Comment: Nothing in there let us know when the code is executed, nor what could make you think it is async...

Comment: As the code fragment shows, i comment the line2 to line4, and put a breakpoint at line6. When the code runs to the breakpoint, I will execute the "drawImage" in chrome console. The command "drawImage" works in Chrome69&FireFox immediately. But in Chrome70, sometimes it works immediately, sometimes it works later(the test_canvas shows nothing). I'm sure the video is available. That is why I think it is async in chrome70.

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: It works, but not synchronously. When the video is ready to render, I execute the "drawImage" in chrome console. Sometimes the test canvas still keep white. Then i keep the code going on, the test canvas show the correct video frame later.So i think the method "drawImage" works asynchronously in Chrome70

Comment: no that does just mean the canvas has not been painted to screen. That is a CSS rendering thing, but drawImage is still most probably synchronous. To convince yourself, call ctx.getImageData just after the call, or even just fill a rect on top of this image. If it is not synchronous then file a bug report right ahead as that would make this method unreliable and would break all code that actually do something on top of an drawImage.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that by imply calling `getImageData()` or even just `fillRect()` right after your `drawImage()` call.
If the returned ImageData is empty, or if there is no rect drawn over your video frame, then, yes, it might be async, which would be a terrible bug that you should report right away.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var vid = document.createElement('video');
vid.muted = true;
vid.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
vid.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm'
vid.play().then(() => {
  ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0);
  console.log(
    "imageData empty",
    ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data.some(d => !!d) === false
  );
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
});
document.body.append(canvas);
```

So now, to give a better explanation as to what you saw, the debugger will stop the whole event loop, and Chrome might have decided to not honor the next CSS frame drawing when the debugger has been called. Hence, what is painted on your screen is still the frame from when your script got called (when no image was drawn).

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var vid = document.createElement('video');
vid.muted = true;
vid.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
vid.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm'
vid.play().then(() => {
  ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0);
  const hasPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data.some(d => !!d);
  alert('That should also block the Event loop and css painting. But drawImage already happened: ' + hasPixels)
});
document.body.append(canvas);
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid;
}
```